# MS Access: referring to a subform textbox control element in VBA query definition

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a subform with user input (text box), that can reach more than 255 chars and can have special characters. As I cannot assign it as a parameter to a vba query definition (only 255 characters will work), I thought about directly referencing the text box:

```
Insert into ...
Values (Forms!MainFormName!txt_MyTextField, ... )
```

does work in a query in the Access GUI, but not in a vba query definition specified with the following code:

```
Set query_definition = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("", SQLQuery))
```

"Forms!MainFormName!NameOfSubformNavigationElement!txt_MyTextField" does not work either as a reference, just in case you are wondering. Neither does "Forms!MainFormName!NameOfSubformNavigationElement.Form.txt_MyTextField"

How can I get what I want? The string can have any kind of special chars like ' and ". Is there no alternative than appending the user input into the sql query? Is there some built-in function to escape these values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: Added another example now that the environment is known.

To use the form field in an action query, create a public function that will return the desired field, then call that function from your query.

```
Public Function GetFormField() As String
    GetFormField = Forms![MyMainForm]!MySub.Form.MyField
End Function
```

In your query, use something like:

```
WHERE ((([106thZip_code_database].zipcode)=GetFormField()));
```

The following is an example you could use in the Main form to reference a field in a subform. 'MySub' is the name of the control on the Main form - not the subform's object name.

```
Debug.Print Forms![MyMainForm]!MySub.Form.MyField
```

A good reference on this subject can be found at: http://access.mvps.org/access/forms/frm0031.htm

Comment: I try to use it in an SQL query via a query definition (Object Type QueryDef). The query definition will than be executed via query_definition.Execute. I do not want to use the reference in vba code, but in an sql query, so if it works with debug.Print does not mean it will work within an insert into-SQL query

Comment: Thank you very much, it works! :) The reference I used in my function is Forms![MyMainForm]!MySubNavigation!txt_MyField, an additional 'Form' in the structure does not work for me.

Comment: Interesting that it doesn't work for you. If I try your syntax (without the second 'Form' and using  a period before the field name, I get error 438 (object doesn't support this property or method). But when I omit the second 'Form' but replace the period with '!' it works. Glad you got it to work!